# "it's not that somebody + verb" construction

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage, construction

I often see this construction "**it's not that somebody + verb**"  and just wish to clarify whether I'm understanding it correctly.

1. **It's not that he doesn't** like coffee that he doesn't want it now, he loves coffee but the doctors said he shouldn't drink it very often.
2. **It's not that Alice hates** cat's it's just that she's allergic to them. *(should there be a comma before "**it's**")*

So the construction basically inverts the meaning, "**not that he doesn't**"="**he does**" and "**not that Alice hates**" = "**she doesn't hate**". Is it some kind of a double negative inversion?

Answer (score 1):

This is a double negative but it places emphasis on contradicting what someone might initially conclude. Here are some usage examples.

First Example

> *Adam drinks water while out for coffee with some coworkers...*
>
> Alice - "Does Adam not like coffee?"
>
> Arnold - "It's not because he doesn't like coffee that he doesn't want it now. He loves coffee, but the doctors said he shouldn't drink it very often."

Second Example

> *Alice keeps some distance from a friend's cat. Afterwards, this friend is talking to another of Alice's friends who knows about the allergy.*
>
> Observer friend - "Does Alice not like cats?"
>
> Allergy-knowing friend - "It's not that Alice hates cats; it's just that she's allergic to them."

In the second example, you might also hear the more brief phrases:

> It's not that Alice hates cats; she's just allergic to them.
>
> It's not that Alice hates cats; she's just allergic.
>
> Alice doesn't hate cats; she's just allergic.

This structure can also be used in the first person to correct someone's misconceptions about you. For example, "It's not that I don't like X, I just ..." is very commonly used to deny dislike for something.

Comment: Hmm.. So I did understand it right. what about the comma in the second example?

Comment: I think a semicolon works better since the two pieces of the sentence stand on their own. They both would sound about the same spoken. I originally copied and pasted the examples but I fixed them in an edit.